# proof check: bound on total variation distance of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, coupling

Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be two probability measures on a discrete set $X$.
Define the total variation distance between $\mu_1,\mu_2$ in terms of coupling as 
$$d(\mu_1,\mu_2) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mu_1,\mu_2)}\gamma(\{(x_1,x_2) | x_1\neq x_2\})$$
where $\Gamma(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ is the set of couplings of $\mu_1,\mu_2$, a coupling being a probability measure on $X\times X$ with marginals $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.

I want to prove that if $\inf_{x} \mu_1(x) \geq \epsilon$ and $\inf_{x}\mu_2(x) \geq \epsilon$, then 
$$d(\mu_1,\mu_2) \leq 1-\epsilon$$ Is the following correct?

Consider the product coupling  $\gamma(x_1,x_2) = \mu_1(x_1)\mu_2(x_2)$. Then
\begin{align*}
d(\mu_1,\mu_2) &\leq \gamma(\{ (x_1,x_2) | x_1\neq x_2 \}) \\
               &=  1 - \gamma(\{(x_1,x_2) | x_1 = x_2\}) \\
               &=  1- \sum\limits_{x}\gamma(x,x) \\
               &=  1 - \sum\limits_{x}\mu_1(x)\mu_2(x) \\
               &\leq  1- \sum\limits_{x}\mu_1(x)\epsilon \\
               &=  1- \epsilon
\end{align*}